# How to use "%f" to populate a double value into a string with the right precision

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, printf

I am trying to populate a string with a double value using a `sprintf` like this:

```
sprintf(S, "%f", val);
```

But the precision is being cut off to six decimal places. I need about 10 decimal places for the precision.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

%[width].[precision]

Width should include the decimal point.

%8.2 means 8 characters wide; 5 digits before the point and 2 after. One character is reserved for the point.

5 + 1 + 2 = 8

Answer (score 7):

What you want is a modifier:

```
sprintf(S, "%.10f", val);
```

man sprintf will have many more details on format specifiers.

Comment: Just a note: if he's using a double, would using "lf" be more correct?

Comment: floats only carry about 6 digits of precision.  use %lf for a double.

Comment: @EvilTeach: Wrong. %f is for doubles. There's no format specifier for floats. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860850/what-is-the-difference-between-f-and-lf-in-c

Answer (score 1):

For a more complete reference, see the [Wikipedia *printf* article, section "printf format placeholders"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#printf_format_placeholders) and [a good example on the same page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#1970s:_C.2C_Lisp).

Answer (score 1):

Take care - the output of sprintf will vary via C locale.  This may or may not be what you want.  See LC_NUMERIC in the locale docs/man pages.

Answer (score 1):

`%f` is for float values.

Try using `%lf` instead. It is designed for doubles (which used to be called long floats).

**double x = 3.14159265**; 
**printf("15.10lf\n", x);**