# 'sprintf': double precision in C

Tags: c

Consider:

```
double a = 0.0000005l;
char aa[50];
sprintf(aa, "%lf", a);
printf("%s", aa);

Output: s0.000000
```

In the above code snippet, the variable `aa` can contain only six decimal precision. I would like to get an output like "s0.0000005". How do I achieve this?

Comment: FYI, 0.0000005l is a "long double", use just 0.0000005 for a constant of type double.

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69743/how-to-use-f-to-populate-a-double-value-into-a-string-with-the-right-precision

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From your question it seems like you are using C99, as you have used `%lf` for double.

To achieve the desired output replace:

```
sprintf(aa, "%lf", a);
```

with

```
sprintf(aa, "%0.7f", a);
```

The general syntax `"%A.B"` means to use B digits after decimal point. The meaning of the `A` is more complicated, but can be read about [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: `"%A.B"` _does not_ mean `A` digits before decimal point. `A` is the _"field width"_.  It is the minimum character width of the entire printed number.  Output is padded with spaces (by default) as needed.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer suggests switching from `lf` to `f`. `lf` is a perfectly appropriate format specifier for `double`. Moreover, it was legalized in C99 specifically to fix than annoying inconsistency between format specifiers in `fscanf` and `fprintf`. Which means that `lf` should be *preferred* over `f` for `double` values. `f` is for `float`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to write it like `sprintf(aa, "%9.7lf", a)`

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf for some more details on format codes.

Comment: %lf is for long double.  %9.7f should be used for a double.

Comment: @kk6yb: `%lf` is undefined for C89, and the same as `%f` for C99 (where both are good to print `double` values). For a long double, the correct conversion specifier is `%Lf`.

Comment: More precisely, in `'%X.Yf'` the `Y` represents the number of places after the decimal to display (the default is 6) and the `X` represents the minimum number of characters to display.  In your case the `X` is not necessary, but you will need to add the `.Y` where `Y` is the number of decimal places to print.

Comment: @pmg: you are correct, %Lf is for long doubles. It's different from the literal constants, where 0.0l and 0.0L both specify a long double literal.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is with sprintf

```
sprintf(aa,"%lf",a);
```

%lf says to interpet "a" as a "long double" (16 bytes) but it is actually a "double" (8 bytes).  Use this instead:

```
sprintf(aa, "%f", a);
```

More details [here on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/)

Comment: `%lf` is undefined for C89, and the same as `%f` for C99. For a long double, the correct conversion specifier is `%Lf`.

Comment: That will print 6 decimal places - so it will most likely print 0.000000 rather than 0.000001.  Using "%9.7f" is correct for 7 decimal places.

Comment: Hmmm, yes, I didn't pay attention to the decimal places. Point is that `%lf` expects a `double` in C99; `%Lf` expects a `long double`.

Comment: @pmg: since a double is passed (and would be even if 'a' was float), there isn't a problem with using "%9.7lf" that I can see.