# Removing the trailing zeros in a double variable

Tags: c++, formatting, double, floating-point-precision

i have a DLL which defines many methods which all returns `double` and I don't want to change anything in it. The problem is when I pass small numbers to these methods, the return values come with too many trailing zeros as the return value is `double`, for example `9*9=810000000000`(it's not a decimal point,it's the actual capacity of a Double variable). i want the normal behavior which is 9*9=81

How can I get rid of those trailing zeros without changing the DLL?

Comment: Divide the result by 10000000000 on the client.

Comment: What language do you use? You should tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786497/sprintf-double-precision-in-c ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by getting rid of trailing zeros? Do you want to change the numeric value of the result, or just the way it's represented as text? What operations are these methods supposed to perform? For `9*9`, are you getting `810000000000`, or is it `81.0000000000`?

Comment: yes the way it's represented, and when i tried 9*9 i got 81000000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Presumably your example should include a decimal point between the 81 and all those zeros?)

Surely if the result is a double, the trailing zeros are only relevant when you render the number it contains into text?

That being the case, all you need to do is format that text at the point where you need it.

Not knowing which language you're working in, I can't offer you the precise syntax for that formatting command, but a quick search on here should help you with that.

Comment: The OP updated the tags; the language is C++. But I'm still not sure what the OP is asking; see my comment on the question.

Comment: I started with the assumption that the lack of a decimal point was a typo, and a second assumption that he was outputting the number as text at some point. I'm not sure it's quite a duplicate of the sprintf question, though that answer might help the OP, certainly.