# What is the difference between %f and %lf in C?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, format-string

I have seen these two parameters in a C example in a C book, but the author didn't elaborate what the difference between the two is. I know that `%f` specifies that a `float` should take its place. I have tried looking this up but have had a hard time finding an explanation. What about `%lf`?

Comment: Rather than looking up `%f` and `%lf`, did you try looking up `printf` or `fprintf`?

Comment: You might find [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) handy. Of course there's also [a reference for `scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: In the C standard look up "The fprintf function" , it covers everything

Comment: Read the documentation of [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The short answer is that it has no impact on `printf`, and denotes use of `float` or `double` in `scanf`.

For `printf`, arguments of type `float` are promoted to `double` so both `%f` and `%lf` are used for `double`. For `scanf`, you should use `%f` for `float` and `%lf` for `double`.

More detail for the language lawyers among us below:

---

There is no difference between `%f` and `%lf` in the `printf` family. The ISO C standard (all references within are from C11), section `7.21.6.1 The fprintf function`, paragraph `/7` states, for the `l` modifier (my emphasis):

> Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `long int` or `unsigned long int` argument; that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `long int` argument; that a following `c` conversion specifier applies to a `wint_t` argument; that a following `s` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `wchar_t` argument; **or has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier.**

The reason it doesn't need to modify the `f` specifier is because that specifier *already* denotes a `double`, from paragraph `/8` of that same section where it lists the type for the `%f` specifier:

> A `double` argument representing a floating-point number is converted to decimal notation

That has to do with the fact that arguments following the ellipse in the function prototype are subject to default argument promotions as per section `6.5.2.2 Function calls`, paragraph `/7`:

> The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

Since `printf` (and the entire *family* of `printf`-like functions) is declared as `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);` with the ellipsis notation, that rule applies here. The default argument promotions are covered in section `6.5.2.2 Function calls`, paragraph `/6`:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and **arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the default argument promotions.**

---

For the `scanf` family, it mandates the use of a `double` rather than a `float`. Section `7.21.6.2 The fscanf function /11`:

> Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, or `n` conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `long int` or `unsigned long int`; **that a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `double`;** or that a following `c`, `s`, or `[` conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `wchar_t`.

This modifies the `/12` paragraph of that section that states, for `%f`:

> Matches an optionally signed floating-point number, infinity, or `NaN`, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtod` function. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to floating.

Answer (score 32):

For `scanf`, `%f` reads into a `float`, and `%lf` reads into a `double`.

For `printf`: In C99 and later, they both are identical, and they print either a `float` or a `double`. In C89, `%lf` caused undefined behaviour although it was a common extension to treat it as `%f`.

The reason that one specifier can be used for two different types in `printf` is because of the *default argument promotions*; arguments of type `float` are promoted to `double` when used to call a function and not matching a parameter in a function prototype. So `printf` just sees a `double` in either case.

Answer (score 4):

For output using the printf family of functions, the %f and %lf specifiers mean the same thing; the l is ignored. Both require a corresponding argument of type double — but an argument of type float is promoted to double, which is why there’s no separate specifier for type float. (This promotion applies only to variadic functions like printf and to functions declared without a prototype, not to function calls in general.) For type long double, the correct format specifier is %Lf.

For input using the scanf family of functions, the floating-point format specifiers are %f, %lf, and %Lf. These require pointers to objects of type float, double, and long double, respectively. (There’s no float-to-double promotion because the arguments are pointers. A float value can be promoted to double, but a float* pointer can’t be promoted to a double* because the pointer has to point to an actual float object.)

But be careful using the scanf functions with numeric input. There is no defined overflow checking, and if the input is outside the range of the type your program’s behavior is undefined. For safety, read input into a string and then use something like strtod to convert it to a numeric value. (See the documentation to find out how to detect errors.)

Answer (score 3):

The width modifier in %lf is gracefully ignored by printf().  Or, to be more accurate, %f takes a double - varargs will always promote float arguments to double.