# Get Wrong answer in c++

Tags: c++

```
double getcircleArea(int radius, double pi);

double getcircleArea(int radius = 1, double pi = 3.14)
{
    return radius*radius*pi;
}

int main()
    {
        printf("area:%d\n", getcircleArea());
        printf("area:%d\n", getcircleArea(10));
        printf("area:%d\n", getcircleArea(15, 3.14159));
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Just a simple example.

I get  result:

area:1374389535
area:0
area:-1408749273

I want is ...
area:3.14
area:314
area: 706.85775

Comment: Few questionable things - >> `double getcircleArea(int radius = 1, double pi = 3.14)` ?? And don't  pass `double` to `%d` in `printf`.  Pass 2 arguments in call to function.

Comment: %d is int. %f is for a double.

Comment: @ameyCU Those are default parameter values in C++.

Comment: @immibis Ok wasn't quite aware. Thanks.

Comment: @immibis It still doesn't make sense to pass pi as an argument.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and it should have told you about mismatched format specifiers with types in plain English. If not, switch compilers.

Comment: @Bernhard: it might make a *little* sense if your program's printing out the different answers you'd get for different approximations of `pi` (e.g. *"if you use 22/7 your answer will be X, but the real value's Y"*), but even in that unusual case `pi_approximation` would be a better identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%d use integer format to print the value. If you want to print float, you should use %f.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `printf`.

```
std::cout << "area: " << getcircleArea() << "\n";
```

works without you having to remember obscure % codes ("%d? I though it means 'double'!")

Comment: Remembering obscure format specifiers is no harder than remembering obscure format functions (setting field widths etc), really, but complete lack of type safety is a better reason to avoid printf.

Answer (score 2):

`%d` is used for `int` data type. Use `%lf` for `double`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double getcircleArea(int radius = 1, double pi = 3.14){
    return (radius*radius*pi);
}

int main(){  
        printf("area:%lf\n", getcircleArea()); // %d --> %lf
        printf("area:%lf\n", getcircleArea(10));  // %d --> %lf
        printf("area:%lf\n", getcircleArea(15, 3.14159));  // %d --> %lf
        system("pause")
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: There is no %lf. Use %f for double, %Lf for long double. Printf uses ... varargs, floats are passed as double.

Comment: @AndrewL In C++, simply use `cout` but as you are using `printf()` from C which is sub set of C++. so I don't see any problem. You can use all the methods from C in C++.

Comment: @hyde  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860850/what-is-the-difference-between-f-and-lf-in-c

Comment: @hyde C++ uses the C99 version of printf, which has `%lf` for double

Comment: @AndrewL. I'm sure. can you share link here.

Comment: Ahh, I see. My bad!

Comment: prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
        prog.cpp:9:45: error: 'printf' was not declared in this scope
         printf("area:%lf\n", getcircleArea()); // %d --> %lf
                                             ^
       prog.cpp:12:23: error: 'system' was not declared in this scope
         system("pause")
                       ^

Answer (score 2):

Your `printf()` is formatting incorrectly. You are supplying a `%d` placeholder, which stands for decimal or base 10 number, but you should supply it with a `%f` placeholder to signify a floating point number.

```
printf("Area: %f\n", getcircleArea(10, 3.14));
```

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) is a good reference for the `printf()` function and provides all the available specifier characters.

You can also just use `cout` from the standard namespace like so:

```
std::cout << "Area: " << getcircleArea(10, 3.14);
```

I would also suggest not to pass PI as an argument as there is a more precise constant value from math.h. You can them access it by doing the following:

```
M_PI
```

Or, as @M.M suggested, you can get PI by finding the arccosine of -1 which returns PI like so:

```
double PI = acos(-1.0);
```

Or you can set it as a constant like so:

```
const long double PI = 3.141592653589793238L;
const double PI = 3.141592653589793;
const float PI = 3.1415927;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. If you are not creating and using objects in your code, the entire purpose of OOP is defeated. So please create and use objects as shown in the code below.

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   class overloading
   {
    public: 
    int getcircleArea()
    {
     cout<<"area is "<< 0 <<"\n";
    }
    double getcircleArea(int radius)
    {
     cout<<"area is "<< radius*radius*3.14<<"\n";
    }
    double getcircleArea(int radius, float pi)
    {
     cout<<"area is "<< radius*radius*pi<<"\n";
    }
   };

int main()
{
    overloading overload1;

    overload1.getcircleArea();
    overload1.getcircleArea(10);
    overload1.getcircleArea(15, 3.14159);

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**: It looks like you are practicing Function Overloading concept. In your code, you have declared a function:

```
 double getcircleArea(int radius = 1, double pi = 3.14)
 {
 return radius*radius*pi; 
 }
```

.....and you are parsing other values to this very function in your `main`program as shown below:

```
  printf("area:%d\n", getcircleArea(15, 3.14159))
```

**I would not recommend this kind of programming to you !!**

Comment: Good ! Keep going ! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are multiplying the square of the radius with the value of PI it becomes double value. So, to print double value use %lf inside the print function. You can also use %f instead of %lf.

```
printf("area: %lf\n", getcircleArea(10, 3.14));
```

While using c++ I would recommend you to use cout instead of print as you do not need the format specifiers like `"%d"`,`"%f"` etc. Using court the code should look like this.

```
cout<<"area: "<<getcircleArea(10,3.14)<<endl;
```