# Why am I getting 123.123000 in the output?

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand to why I'm not getting `123.123` in the output. Should I be using the `f` instead of `lf`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    double foo = 123.123;
    int blah = 54321;

     printf("%d\n", blah);
     printf("%10d \n", blah);
     printf("%08d\n",blah);
     printf("%10d \n", blah);
     printf("%010d \n", blah);
     printf("%lf\n", foo);      // Why am I getting 123.123000?
     printf("%.4f\n", foo);
     printf("%4.2f \n", foo);
}
```

Comment: You know that 123.123 and 123.123000 are the same number, right?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting `123.123000` because by default `"%lf"` prints to 6 decimal places. Instead, use `%.3lf`.

Answer (score 2):

The default precision for `%f` is 6 decimal places, hence the output `123.123000`.

To remove the trailing zeroes of the fractional part (and the decimal point if no decimals are left), use `%g`.

Note that the `l` in `%lf` is necessary in a `scanf` format to convert a number into a `double` variable, but it is useless for `printf` where all floating point values are passed as `double`. So `%lf` and `%f` behave exactly the same for `printf`.

Note also that the prototype for `main` is `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) or equivalent.

Comment: so by replacing if with f will output 123.123 ..?

Comment: No, you will get `123.123` with `printf("%g\n", foo);`.  `%lf` and `%f` behave exactly the same for `printf`.

Comment: so f and if behave the same but if must only be used when reading input thats good to know thank you sir

Comment: it is not `if`, it is `lf` (ell eff).  `%lf` is used to read `double` values, `%f` is used to read `float` values in `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `%lf`, just tell it how many digits of precision you want (e.g. 3):

`printf("%.3lf,\n" foo); //prints 123.123`

Comment: Or use `%g` in case you do not know how many are significant in the first 6.

Answer (score 0):

That's just the default precision. In the `printf` function `%lf` and `%f` are interpreted in the same way. The real difference is in the `scanf` function where `%lf` reads the value as double and `%f` reads the value as float. 
There's an interesting post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860850/what-is-the-difference-between-f-and-lf-in-c)

Comment: so when reading input using scanf you are to always use if right ?

Comment: For diubles, yes :)