# Stray characters seen at output of snprintf

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I have a string creating function in C which accepts an `array of structs` as it's argument and outputs a string based on a predefined format (like a list of list in python).
Here's the function

```
typedef struct
{
    PacketInfo_t PacketInfo;
    char Gnss60[1900]; 
    //and other stuff...
} Track_json_t;

typedef struct 
{
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
} GPSPoint_t;

typedef struct
{
    UInt16          GPS_StatusCode;
    UInt32          fixtime;
    GPSPoint_t      point;
    double          altitude;
    unsigned char GPS_Satilite_Num;
} GPS_periodic_t;

unsigned short SendTrack()
{
    Track_json_t i_sTrack_S;
    memset(&i_sTrack_S, 0x00, sizeof(Track_json_t));
    getEvent_Track(&i_sTrack_S);
    //Many other stuff added to the i_sTrack_S struct...
    //Make a JSON format out of it
    BuildTrackPacket_json(&i_sTrack_S, XPORT_MODE_GPRS);
}

Track_json_t *getEvent_Track(Track_json_t *trk)
{
    GPS_periodic_t l_gps_60Sec[60];
    memset(&l_gps_60Sec, 0x00,
           sizeof(GPS_periodic_t) * GPS_PERIODIC_ARRAY_SIZE);
    getLastMinGPSdata(l_gps_60Sec, o_gps_base);
    get_gps60secString(l_gps_60Sec, trk->Gnss60);
    return trk;
}

void get_gps60secString(GPS_periodic_t input[60], char *output)
{
    int i = 0;
    memcpy(output, "[", 1); ///< Copy the first char as [
    char temp[31];
    for (i = 0; i < 59; i++) { //Run for n-1 elements
        memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
        snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "[%0.8f,%0.8f],",
            input[i].point.latitude, input[i].point.longitude);
        strncat(output, temp, sizeof(temp));
    }
    memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp)); //assign last element
    snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "[%0.8f,%0.8f]]",
             input[i].point.latitude, input[i].point.longitude);
    strncat(output, temp, sizeof(temp));
}
```

So the output of the function must be a string of format

> [[12.12345678,12.12345678],[12.12345678,12.12345678],...]

But at times I get a string which looks like

> [[12.12345678,12.12345678],**[55.01**[12.12345678,12.12345678],...]
>   [[21.28211567,84.13454083],**[21.28211533,21.22**[21.28211517,84.13454000],..]

Previously, I had a buffer overflow at the function `get_gps60secString`, I fixed that by using `snprintf` and `strncat`.

Note: This is an embedded application and this error occur once or twice a day (out of 1440 packets)

**Question**
1. Could this be caused by an interrupt during the snprintf/strncat process?
2. Could this be caused by a memory leak, overwriting the stack or some other segmentation issue caused else where?
Basically I would like to understand what might be causing a corrupt string.

Having a hard time finding the cause and fixing this bug.

---

**EDIT:**
I used `chux's` function. Below is the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example

```
/*
 * Test code for SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216413
 * A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef unsigned short UInt16;
typedef unsigned long  UInt32;

#define GPS_PERIODIC_ARRAY_SIZE  60
#define GPS_STRING_SIZE          1900

/* ---------------------- Data Structs --------------------------*/
typedef struct
{
    char Gnss60[GPS_STRING_SIZE];
} Track_json_t;

typedef struct
{
    double          latitude;
    double          longitude;
} GPSPoint_t;

typedef struct
{
    UInt16          GPS_StatusCode;
    UInt32          fixtime;
    GPSPoint_t      point;
    double          altitude;
    unsigned char GPS_Satilite_Num;
} GPS_periodic_t;

/* ----------------------- Global --------------------------------*/
FILE *fptr; //Global file pointer
int res = 0;
int g_last = 0;
GPS_periodic_t l_gps_60Sec[GPS_PERIODIC_ARRAY_SIZE];

/* ----------------------- Function defs --------------------------*/

/* At signal interrupt this function is called.
 * Flush and close the file. And safly exit the program */
void userSignalInterrupt()
{
    fflush(fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    res = 1;
    exit(0);
}

/* @brief From the array of GPS structs we create a string of the format
 * [[lat,long],[lat,long],..]
 * @param   input   The input array of GPS structs
 * @param   output  The output string which will contain lat, long
 * @param   sz      Size left in the output buffer
 * @return  0       Successfully completed operation
 *          1       Failed / Error
 */
int get_gps60secString(GPS_periodic_t input[GPS_PERIODIC_ARRAY_SIZE], 
                       char *output, size_t sz) 
{
    int cnt = snprintf(output, sz, "[");
    if (cnt < 0 || cnt >= sz)
        return 1;
    output += cnt;
    sz -= cnt;

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < GPS_PERIODIC_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        cnt = snprintf(output, sz, "[%0.8f,%0.8f]%s", 
                input[i].point.latitude, input[i].point.longitude, 
                i + 1 == GPS_PERIODIC_ARRAY_SIZE ? "" : ",");
        if (cnt < 0 || cnt >= sz)
            return 1;
        output += cnt;
        sz -= cnt;
    }

    cnt = snprintf(output, sz, "]");
    if (cnt < 0 || cnt >= sz)
        return 1;
    return 0; // no error
}

/* @brief   Create a GPS struct with data for testing. It will populate the
 * point field of GPS_periodic_t. Lat starts from 0.0 and increases by 1*10^(-8)
 * and Long will dstart at 99.99999999 and dec by 1*10^(-8)
 *
 * @param   o_gps_60sec Output array of GPS structs
 */
void getLastMinGPSdata(GPS_periodic_t *o_gps_60sec)
{
    //Fill in GPS related data here
    int i = 0;
    double latitude = o_gps_60sec[0].point.latitude;
    double longitude = o_gps_60sec[0].point.longitude;
    for (i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        o_gps_60sec[i].point.latitude = latitude +  (0.00000001 * (float)g_last + 
                                        0.00000001 * (float)i);
        o_gps_60sec[i].point.longitude = longitude -  (0.00000001 * (float)g_last + 
                                        0.00000001 * (float)i);
    }
    g_last = 60;
}

/* @brief   Get the GPS data and convert it into a string
 * @param   trk Track structure with GPS string
 */
int getEvent_Track(Track_json_t *trk)
{
    getLastMinGPSdata(l_gps_60Sec);
    get_gps60secString(l_gps_60Sec, trk->Gnss60, GPS_STRING_SIZE);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    fptr = fopen("gpsAno.txt", "a");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Quit at signal interrupt
    signal(SIGINT, userSignalInterrupt);

    Track_json_t trk;
    memset(&l_gps_60Sec, 0x00, sizeof(GPS_periodic_t) * GPS_PERIODIC_ARRAY_SIZE);

    //Init Points to be zero and 99.99999999
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        l_gps_60Sec[i].point.latitude =  00.00000000;
        l_gps_60Sec[i].point.longitude = 99.99999999;
    }

    do {
        memset(&trk, 0, sizeof(Track_json_t));
        getEvent_Track(&trk);

        //Write to file
        fprintf(fptr, "%s", trk.Gnss60);
        fflush(fptr);
        sleep(1);
    } while (res == 0);

    //close and exit
    fclose(fptr);
    return  0;
}
```

**Note**: Error was not recreated in the above code.
Because this doesn't have the `strcat` pitfalls.
I tested this function in the embedded application.
Through this I was able to find that the `snprintf` returns an error and the string created ended up to be:

> [17.42401750,78.46098717],[17.42402083,**53.62**

It ended there (because of the `return 1`).

Does this mean that the data which was passed to `snprints` corrupted? It's a float value. How can it get corrupted?

**Solution**
The error have not been seen since I changed the `sprintf` function with one that doesn't directly deal with 64 bits of data.

Here's the function `modp_dtoa2`

```
/** \brief convert a floating point number to char buffer with a
 *         variable-precision format, and no trailing zeros
 *
 * This is similar to "%.[0-9]f" in the printf style, except it will
 * NOT include trailing zeros after the decimal point.  This type
 * of format oddly does not exists with printf.
 *
 * If the input value is greater than 1<<31, then the output format
 * will be switched exponential format.
 *
 * \param[in] value
 * \param[out] buf  The allocated output buffer.  Should be 32 chars or more.
 * \param[in] precision  Number of digits to the right of the decimal point.
 *    Can only be 0-9.
 */
void modp_dtoa2(double value, char* str, int prec)
{
    /* if input is larger than thres_max, revert to exponential */
    const double thres_max = (double)(0x7FFFFFFF);
    int count;
    double diff = 0.0;
    char* wstr = str;
    int neg= 0;
    int whole;
    double tmp;
    uint32_t frac;

    /* Hacky test for NaN
     * under -fast-math this won't work, but then you also won't
     * have correct nan values anyways.  The alternative is
     * to link with libmath (bad) or hack IEEE double bits (bad)
     */
    if (! (value == value)) {
        str[0] = 'n'; str[1] = 'a'; str[2] = 'n'; str[3] = '\0';
        return;
    }

    if (prec < 0) {
        prec = 0;
    } else if (prec > 9) {
        /* precision of >= 10 can lead to overflow errors */
        prec = 9;
    }

    /* we'll work in positive values and deal with the
       negative sign issue later */
    if (value < 0) {
        neg = 1;
        value = -value;
    }


    whole = (int) value;
    tmp = (value - whole) * pow10[prec];
    frac = (uint32_t)(tmp);
    diff = tmp - frac;

    if (diff > 0.5) {
        ++frac;
        /* handle rollover, e.g.  case 0.99 with prec 1 is 1.0  */
        if (frac >= pow10[prec]) {
            frac = 0;
            ++whole;
        }
    } else if (diff == 0.5 && ((frac == 0) || (frac & 1))) {
        /* if halfway, round up if odd, OR
           if last digit is 0.  That last part is strange */
        ++frac;
    }

    /* for very large numbers switch back to native sprintf for exponentials.
       anyone want to write code to replace this? */
    /*
      normal printf behavior is to print EVERY whole number digit
      which can be 100s of characters overflowing your buffers == bad
    */
    if (value > thres_max) {
        sprintf(str, "%e", neg ? -value : value);
        return;
    }

    if (prec == 0) {
        diff = value - whole;
        if (diff > 0.5) {
            /* greater than 0.5, round up, e.g. 1.6 -> 2 */
            ++whole;
        } else if (diff == 0.5 && (whole & 1)) {
            /* exactly 0.5 and ODD, then round up */
            /* 1.5 -> 2, but 2.5 -> 2 */
            ++whole;
        }

        //vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  Diff from modp_dto2
    } else if (frac) {
        count = prec;
        // now do fractional part, as an unsigned number
        // we know it is not 0 but we can have leading zeros, these
        // should be removed
        while (!(frac % 10)) {
            --count;
            frac /= 10;
        }
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  Diff from modp_dto2

        // now do fractional part, as an unsigned number
        do {
            --count;
            *wstr++ = (char)(48 + (frac % 10));
        } while (frac /= 10);
        // add extra 0s
        while (count-- > 0) *wstr++ = '0';
        // add decimal
        *wstr++ = '.';
    }

    // do whole part
    // Take care of sign
    // Conversion. Number is reversed.
    do *wstr++ = (char)(48 + (whole % 10)); while (whole /= 10);
    if (neg) {
        *wstr++ = '-';
    }
    *wstr='\0';
    strreverse(str, wstr-1);
}
```

Comment: Will the string you pass as `output` be zero-initialized initially? Otherwise it won't be terminated when you call [`strncat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat) (which it needs to be).

Comment: Yes, it is zero initialized (memset)

Comment: And the buffer pointed to by `output` is big enough? It would be easier to help you if you created a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Please show at least the code where you call `get_gps60secString` including the declaration and initialisation of the relevant variables.

Comment: You are misusing `strncat()` with `strncat(output, temp, sizeof(temp));` — the size should be the amount of space left in the target less 1 for the null byte (so at most `sizeof(output) - 1` if `output` is an array of known size).  Given that your function doesn't know how big the `output` array is, you cannot protect against overflows in that array, and using `strncat()` is a bad idea.  Note that `char buffer[16] = ""; strncat(buffer, "abcdefghijklmnop", sizeof(buffer));` leads to a buffer overflow!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude added a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How should I append the string into the output buffer, if `strncat` is a `bad option`? Wait are you saying a buffer overflow in `output` buffer? I've set it to be a big value (taking into account the size of a GPS string)

Comment: You're still missing a very important bit: The `Track_json_t` type, more specifically its `Gnss60` member. Is it an array or a pointer? And if it's a pointer, where does it point? From the code you show it would be equivalent to a null pointer (if it's a pointer) due to the `memset` call.

Comment: As a tiny note, since this is a bit of a pet peeve, `0x00` is in no way zeroer than `0`. It is, however, needlessly complex and implies that there is a difference, which there is not in this case. They're both integer literals with the value zero.

Comment: Given that you are crossing your fingers and hoping, use `strcat()`.  Using `strncat()` correctly is hard; most people get it wrong.  Using it in the hope that it will protect you when the necessary information is not available (you need the size of `output` as an argument to the function) could lull you into a false sense of security.  Personally, I don't use `strncat()` ever — if I know enough to use it safely, there are better options available, such as `memmove()` or `memcpy()`.  (Knowing enough means how long `output` is, how much is in use, and how much is about to be added.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot simpler for the `for` loop to do all 60 elements, then just `strcat( output, "]" );` to the end?  If your `temp` buffer is big enough, `strncat()` isn't needed.  And if `temp` isn't big enough, `strncat()` won't properly terminate your string...

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Actually, whatever its other faults, `strncat()` always appends a null byte — C11 [§7.24.3.2 The `strncat` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.3.2) says: _… A terminating null character is always appended to the result._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Doh!  I'm thinking of `strncpy()`.  I'll plead too early on a Tuesday morning after a long holiday weekend.  :-)

Comment: ClamentJohn, Is the stray "[21.28211533,21.22" additional unexpected text or is the following "[21.28211517,84.13454000]" unexpectedly overwriting the end of "[21.28211533,21.22......."?

Comment: @chux The valid GPS string must be "[21.28211517,84.13454000]". So in the second one we could say a stray "21.22" + "\0" came into the output string. Will work on creating a compilable code. It's just that it's embedded and I'll have to feed in values for the GPS input.

Comment: I think you need to post a compilable code: .  Lingering issues like what is `GPS_PERIODIC_ARRAY_SIZE`, `getEvent_Track()`, `get_gps60secString()` called before definition, etc. come into play and a [mcve] would save all time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's (part of) my unabashedly opinionated guide on safe string handling in C. Normally, I would promote dynamic memory allocation instead of fixed-length strings, but in this case I'm assuming that in the embedded environment that might be problematic. (Although assumptions like that should always be checked.)

So, first things first:

1. **Any function which creates a string in a buffer must be told explicitly how long the buffer is. This is non-negotiable.**

   As should be obvious, it's impossible for a function filling a buffer to check for buffer overflow unless it knows where the buffer ends. "Hope that the buffer is long enough" is not a viable strategy. "Document the needed buffer length" would be fine if everyone carefully read the documentation (they don't) and if the required length never changes (it will). The only thing that's left is an extra argument, which should be of type `size_t` (because that's the type of buffer lengths in the C library functions which require lengths).
2. **Forget that `strncpy` and `strncat` exist. Also forget about `strcat`. They are not your friends.**

   `strncpy` is designed for a specific use case: ensuring that an entire fixed-length buffer is initialised. It is not designed for normal strings, and since it doesn't guarantee that the output is NUL-terminated, it doesn't produce a string.

   If you're going to NUL-terminate yourself anyway, you might as well use `memmove`, or `memcpy` if you know that the source and destination don't overlap, which should almost always be the case. Since you'll want the `memmove` to stop at the end of the string for short strings (which `strncpy` does *not* do), measure the string length first with `strnlen`: `strnlen` takes a maximum length, which is precisely what you want in the case that you are going move a maximum number of characters.

   Sample code:

   ```c
   /* Safely copy src to dst where dst has capacity dstlen. */
   if (dstlen) {
     /* Adjust to_move will have maximum value dstlen - 1 */
     size_t to_move = strnlen(src, dstlen - 1);
     /* copy the characters */
     memmove(dst, src, to_move);
     /* NUL-terminate the string */
     dst[to_move] = 0;
   }
   ```

   `strncat` has a slightly more sensible semantic, but it's practically never useful because in order to use it, you already have to know how many bytes you could copy. In order to know that, in practice, you need to know how much space is left in your output buffer, and to know that you need to know where in the output buffer the copy will start. [Note 1]. But if you already know where the copy will start, what's the point of searching through the buffer from the beginning to find the copy point? And if you do let `strncat` do the search, how sure are you that your previously computed start point is correct?

   In the above code snippet, we already computed the length of the copy. We can extend that to do an append without rescanning:

   ```c
   /* Safely copy src1 and then src2 to dst where dst has capacity dstlen. */
   /* Assumes that src1 and src2 are not contained in dst. */
   if (dstlen) {
     /* Adjust to_move will have maximum value dstlen - 1 */
     size_t to_move = strnlen(src1, dstlen - 1);
     /* Copy the characters from src1 */
     memcpy(dst, src1, to_move);
     /* Adjust the output pointer and length */
     dst += to_move;
     dstlen -= to_move;
     /* Now safely copy src2 to just after src1. */
     to_move = strnlen(src2, dstlen - 1);
     memcpy(dst, src2, to_move);
     /* NUL-terminate the string */
     dst[to_move] = 0;
   }
   ```

   It might be that we want the original values of `dst` and `dstlen` after creating the string, and it might also be that we want to know how many bytes we inserted into `dst` in all. In that case, we would probably want to make copies of those variables before doing the copies, and save the cumulative sum of moves.

   The above assumes that we're starting with an empty output buffer, but perhaps that isn't the case. Since we still need to know where the copy will start in order to know how many characters we can put at the end, we can still use `memcpy`; we just need to scan the output buffer first to find the copy point. (Only do this if there is no alternative. Doing it in a loop instead of recording the next copy point is [Shlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).)

   ```c
   /* Safely append src to dst where dst has capacity dstlen and starts
    * with a string of unknown length.
    */
   if (dstlen) {
     /* The following code will "work" even if the existing string
      * is not correctly NUL-terminated; the code will not copy anything
      * from src, but it will put a NUL terminator at the end of the
      * output buffer.
      */
     /* Figure out where the existing string ends. */
     size_t prefixlen = strnlen(dst, dstlen - 1);
     /* Update dst and dstlen */
     dst += prefixlen;
     dstlen -= prefixlen;
     /* Proceed with the append, as above. */
     size_t to_move = strnlen(src, dstlen - 1);
     memmove(dst, src, to_move);
     dst[to_move] = 0;
   }
   ```
3. **Embrace `snprintf`. It really is your friend. But always check its return value.**

   Using `memmove`, as above, is slightly awkward. It requires you to manually check that the buffer's length is not zero (otherwise subtracting one would be disastrous since the length is unsigned), and it requires you to manually NUL-terminate the output buffer, which is easy to forget and the source of many bugs. It is very efficient, but sometimes it's worth sacrificing a little efficiency so that your code is easier to write and easier to read and verify.

   And that leads us directly to `snprintf`. For example, you can replace:

   ```c
   if (dstlen) {
     size_t to_move = strnlen(src, dstlen - 1);
     memcpy(dst, src, to_move);
     dst[to_move] = 0;
   }
   ```

   with the much simpler

   ```c
   int copylen = snprintf(dst, dstlen, "%s", src);
   ```

   That does everything: checks that `dstlen` is not 0; only copies the characters from `src` which can fit in `dst`, and correctly NUL-terminates `dst` (unless `dstlen` was 0). And the cost is minimal; it takes very little time to parse the format string `"%s"` and most implementations are pretty well optimised for this case. [Note 2]

   But `snprintf` is not a panacea. There are still a couple of really important warnings.

   First, the documentation for `snprintf` makes clear that it is not permitted for any input argument to overlap the output range. (So it replaces `memcpy` but not `memmove`.) Remember that overlap includes NUL-terminators, so the following code which attempts to double the string in `str` instead leads to *Undefined Behaviour*:

   ```c
   char str[BUFLEN];
   /* Put something into str */
   get_some_data(str, BUFLEN);

   /* DO NOT DO THIS: input overlaps output */
   int result = snprintf(str, BUFLEN, "%s%s", str, str);

   /* DO NOT DO THIS EITHER; IT IS STILL UB */
   size_t len = strnlen(str, cap - 1);
   int result = snprintf(str + len, cap - len, "%s", str);
   ```

   The problem with the second invocation of `snprintf` is that the NUL which terminates `str` is precisely at `str + len`, the first byte of the output buffer. That's an overlap, so it's illegal.

   The second important note about `snprintf` is that it returns a value, which must not be ignored. The value returned is not the length of the string created by `snprintf`. It's the length the string would have been had it not been truncated to fit in the output buffer.

   If no truncation occurred, then the result is the length of the result, which must be *strictly less than* the size of the output buffer (because there must be room for a NUL terminator, which is not considered part of the length of the result.) You can use this fact to check whether truncation occurred:

   ```c
   if (result >= dstlen) /* Output was truncated */
   ```

   This can be used, for example, to redo the `snprintf` with a larger, dynamically-allocated buffer (of size `result + 1`; never forget the need to NUL-terminate).

   But remember that the result is an `int` -- that is, a signed value. That means that `snprintf` cannot cope with very long strings. That's not likely to be an issue in embedded code, but on systems where it's conceivable that strings exceed 2GB, you may not be able to safely use `%s` formats in `snprintf`. It also means that `snprintf` is allowed to return a negative value to indicate an error. Very old implementations of `snprintf` returned -1 to indicate truncation, or in response to being called with buffer length 0. That's not standard behaviour according to C99 (nor recent versions of Posix), but you should be prepared for it.

   Standard-compliant implementations of `snprintf` will return a negative value if the buffer length argument is too big to fit in a (signed) `int`; it's not clear to me what the expected return value is if the buffer length is OK but the untruncated length is too big for an `int`. A negative value will also be returned if you used a conversion which resulted in an encoding error; for example, a `%lc` conversion whose corresponding argument contains an integer which cannot be converted to a multibyte (typically UTF-8) sequence.

   In short, you should always check the return value of `snprintf` (recent gcc/glibc versions will produce a warning if you do not), and you should be prepared for it to be negative.

---

So, with all that behind us, let's write a function which produces a string of co-ordinate pairs:

```c
/* Arguments:
 *    buf      the output buffer.
 *    buflen   the capacity of buf (including room for trailing NUL).
 *    points   a vector of struct Point pairs.
 *    npoints  the number of objects in points.
 * Description:
 *    buf is overwritten with a comma-separated list of points enclosed in
 *    square brackets. Each point is output as a comma-separated pair of
 *    decimal floating point numbers enclosed in square brackets. No more
 *    than buflen - 1 characters are written. Unless buflen is 0, a NUL is
 *    written following the (possibly-truncated) output.
 * Return value:
 *    If the output buffer contains the full output, the number of characters
 *    written to the output buffer, not including the NUL terminator.
 *    If the output was truncated, (size_t)(-1) is returned.
 */
 size_t sprint_points(char* buf, size_t buflen,
                      struct Point const* points, size_t npoints)
 { 
   if (buflen == 0) return (size_t)(-1);
   size_t avail = buflen;
   char delim = '['
   while (npoints) {
     int res = snprintf(buf, avail, "%c[%f,%f]",
                        delim, points->lat, points->lon);
     if (res < 0 || res >= avail) return (size_t)(-1);
     buf += res; avail -= res;
     ++points; --npoints;
     delim = ',';
  }
  if (avail <= 1) return (size_t)(-1);
  strcpy(buf, "]");
  return buflen - (avail - 1);
}
```

#### Notes

1. You will often see code like this:

   ```c
   strncat(dst, src, sizeof(src)); /* NEVER EVER DO THIS! */
   ```

   Telling `strncat` not to append more characters from `src` than can fit in `src` is obviously pointless (unless `src` is not correctly NUL-terminated, in which case you have a bigger problem). More importantly, it does *absolutely nothing* to protect you from writing beyond the end of the output buffer, since you have not done anything to check that `dst` has room for all those characters. So about all it does is get rid of compiler warnings about the unsafety of `strcat`. Since this code is *exactly as unsafe* as `strcat` was, you probably would be better off with the warning.
2. You might even find a compiler which understands `snprintf` will enough to parse the format string at compile time, so the convenience comes at no cost at all. (And if your current compiler doesn't do this, no doubt a future version will.) As with any use of the `*printf` family, you should *never* try to economize keystrokes by 
   leaving out the format string (`snprintf(dst, dstlen, src)` instead of `snprintf(dst, dstlen, "%s", src)`.) That's *unsafe* (it has undefined behaviour if `src` contains an unduplicated `%`). And it's *much slower* because the library function has to parse the entire string to be copied looking for percent signs, instead of just copying it to the output.

Comment: I haven't proofread any of that code yet; I went for lunch. If you see an error, let me know and I'll cheerfully fix it when I get back.

Comment: I'm passing `double` points, but in my sprintf I'm expecting a `%f`  float. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860850/what-is-the-difference-between-f-and-lf-in-c  for `printf` family `%f` & `%lf` are the same. My arm-gcc version is C99. Will it have an issue here?

Comment: It looks like from C99 and later, `printf` family accepts double (`%f` and `%lf`) https://stackoverflow.com/a/25860890/5698740

Comment: @clmno: The `%f` printf format prints a `double`. It always has done and it will always do so. C99 graciously allowed the redundant `l` flag, but it changes nothing. It is impossible to print a `float` directly because varargs functions like `printf` cannot take `float` arguments. They also can't take `short` or `char` arguments. You can call the function with such values, of course, but `floats` will be converted to `double` and integer types narrower than an `int` will be converted to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Code is using functions that expect pointers to *string*, yet not always passing pointers to *strings* as arguments.

> Stray characters seen at output of snprintf

A *string* must have a terminating *null character*.

`strncat(char *, ....` expects the first parameter to be a pointer to a string.  `memcpy(output, "[",1);` does not insure that.  [@Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52164399/2410359)

```
memcpy(output, "[",1);
...
strncat(output, temp,sizeof(temp));
```

This is a candidate source of *stray characters*.

---

`strncat(...., ..., size_t size).` itself is a problem as the `size` is the amount of space available for concatenating (minus the null character). The size available to `char * output` is not passed in. [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164135/stray-characters-seen-at-output-of-snprintf#comment91278368_52164135).  Might as well do `strcat()` here.

Instead, pass in the size available to `output` to prevent buffer overflow.

```
#define N 60

int get_gps60secString(GPS_periodic_t input[N], char *output, size_t sz) {
  int cnt = snprintf(output, sz, "[");
  if (cnt < 0 || cnt >= sz)
    return 1;
  output += cnt;
  sz -= cnt;

  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cnt = snprintf(output, size, "[%0.8f,%0.8f]%s", input[i].point.latitude,
        input[i].point.longitude, i + 1 == N ? "" : ",");
    if (cnt < 0 || cnt >= sz)
      return 1;
    output += cnt;
    sz -= cnt;
  }

  cnt = snprintf(output, sz, "]");
  if (cnt < 0 || cnt >= sz)
    return 1;
  return 0; // no error
}
```

---

OP has posted more code - will review.

Apparently  the buffer `char *output` is pre-filled with 0 before the `get_gps60secString()` so the missing *null character* from `memcpy(output, "[",1);` should not cause the issue - hmmmmmm

`unsigned short SendTrack()` does not return a value. 1) Using its result value is UB. 2) Enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: I had not included that. It does have a return. I'll make a compile-able code and share it. But please note that I'll have to work around things like GPS data (HW)

Comment: Related: [What are the functions from the standard library that must/should be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518)

Comment: @Lundin Interesting [list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518).  Aside from `atoi()`, I concur with "functions that should never be used".  Yet in my book  "functions that should be used with caution:" is the rest of the standard library.  It seems every function has a mis-use potential on SO.

Comment: @chux I used the "get_gps60secString" function you made. But still an error was raised. Is this because the data I/P to snprintf is corrupted? Please refer to the edit portion of the question.

Comment: @ClamentJohn I do not think so.  I suspect your buffer is too small. What is nneded is to see how `get_gps60secString()` was called and the value of its arguments.

Comment: I've added a code to show how it's called. How should I give more data? And since this only fails once or twice a day the data that went into the fn is hard to be determined. Also, do you suspect the output buffer to be small? Hmm.. hard to get my head around that. Because it should have failed freq'ly.

Comment: @ClamentJohn This answer's version of `get_gps60secString()` has 3 parameters.  I do not see your code that calls it.

Comment: @chux I've created a C program to reflect the operations  done on the embedded side.