# Debugging for hard to recreate C bug. Dynamic breakpoint

Tags: c, gdb, embedded, gdb-python

I have a hard to recreate bug and I'm hoping to use a `python GDB script` to stop the process when the bug is detected (I'll run it in debug till the error is regenerated). In reference to [Stray chars seen out of snprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164135).

I've currently made a script that can create a `break-point` and parallely reading the `serial` terminal to detect an error in the string. Here's the script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import serial
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import io
import time
import ast
import sys
import signal
import threading


class Serial_Port():
    def __init__(self, port_number, baud_rate):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port_number, baud_rate, timeout=10)
        self.ser_io = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(self.ser, self.ser, 1), newline = '\r', line_buffering = True)
        self.data_count = 0
        self.data_times = 0
        self.data_succ = 0
        self.ifPrint = False

    def read(self):
        raw_line = self.ser_io.readline()
        raw_line = raw_line.strip("\x00")
        raw_line = raw_line.strip("\r\n")

        if self.ifPrint == True:
            fptr.write(raw_line)
        else:
            self.data_times +=1
            # Print the current status of string test
            to_write = "Loop: %d Read Count: %d Successful: %d" % (self.data_times, self.data_count, self.data_succ)
            fptr.write(to_write)
            fptr.write("\n")


        if "[[" in raw_line:
            self.data_count += 1
            self.parse(raw_line)
        #Flush all the data before returning
        fptr.flush()

    def parse(self, gnss):
        try:
            #if we are able to convert literal and a DF made
            # we'll assume the data received is valid
            gnss = ast.literal_eval(gnss)
            df = pd.DataFrame(gnss)
            self.data_succ += 1
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.ser.flush()
            self.ser.close()
            sys.exit(0)
        except:
            fptr.write(gnss)
            fptr.write("\n")
            fptr.flush()

    def close(self, frame, andsomething):
        self.ser.flush()
        self.ser.close()
        sys.exit(0)

class DebugPrintingBreakpoint(gdb.Breakpoint):
    debugging_IDs = frozenset({37, 153, 420})
    def stop(self):
        top = gdb.newest_frame()
        someVector = top.read_var('aVectorVar')
        # Access the begin() & end() pointer of std::vector in GNU Standard C++ lib
        first = someVector['_M_impl']['_M_start']
        last = someVector['_M_impl']['_M_finish']
        values = []
        while first != last:
            values.append(int(first.dereference()['intID']))
            first = first + 1
        if not set(values) & debugging_IDs:
            return False # skip: none of the items we're looking for can be found by ID in the vector on the stack
        print("Found other accompanying IDs: {}".format(values))
        return True # drop to gdb's prompt

class MyThread_serial(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)#sleep for 1s
            serialPort.read()

def main():
    ser_thread = MyThread_serial(name = "Thread-serial")
    ser_thread.start()

    gdb.execute("continue")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fptr = open("gdbOPs.txt", "a") 

    #connect to serial port
    strPort = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
    serialPort = Serial_Port(strPort, 9600)

    #set signal interrupt to exit
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, serialPort.close)
    print('Press Ctrl+C to exit')

    main()
```

**Background**

I have a hardware that is sending a string in the format

> [[12.12345678,12.12345678],[12.12345678,12.12345678],...]

But at times the string can have errors similar to

> [[12.12345678,12.12345678],[**55.01**[12.12345678,12.12345678],...]

I've never been able to reproduce this bug and so I decided to write a script that waits till the error is seen, then `interrupts` GDB. Dump the stack and all the variables that are relevant.

*Please refer to the original C question to learn more of the bug*

**Question**

1. How do I create a dynamic interrupt? I.e when a failed string is seen I should send `Ctrl+C` to stop the process and get control of the prompt.
2. How is my approach to finding the bug? Do people usually use these kind of testing methods? Could you link them?

**Update**

The bug was resolved by replacing the `sprintf` function with a function that doesn't deal with 64 bits (in a 32 bit ARM environment, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388489) question) directly. Please go to the original question to find the new function used.

Comment: about 2 : I usually first try to reproduce, then try to reproduce faster (more than bug occurence a day) then in your case as you seem to see the problem externally, try to find a way to observe it internally (may be breakpoint but may also be a condition check in code with while(1) and then start debug without reset). After that, you are almost done. Debug trace (if your device supports it) is also a wonderful (and addictive) tool.

Comment: About 1: Breakpoint each character the program writes to stdout (or the pipe the string is sended). It would be best if the breakpoint would be on the writing function in the program with some volatile variable used to query the currently written char in gdb. Then write a parser for the string, if it detects a faulty string, that's your breakpoint. Abous 2: Cool

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll keep this question open till I find a solution. I'll post the solution once I find one.