# Could anyone tell me why this code in C is not working how it should?

Tags: c, loops

My goal is to display the sum how many times both loops are passed.

Does anyone know what i did wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    double a;
    a = 0;
    //(a)
    int zaehler;
    for (int zaehler = 0; zaehler != 10; zaehler = zaehler +1);
    {
        a++;
    }
    //(b)
    int n;
    for (n = 917; n > 0; n = n - 0.5)
    {
            a++;
    }


    printf("%.2lf " , a );

}
```

The first for loop only has one pass and the second only 917. Although the first shouls have 10 and the second 1834.

Comment: `for (int zaehler = 0; zaehler != 10; zaehler = zaehler +1);` why the semicolon? this loop (it is a complete loop) does nothing other than setting `zaehler`. The following block `{ a++; }` executes as if it was a single statement: it's a "free" block (belongs to `main()` alone).

Comment: Also `n = n - 0.5` is not doing what you think since `n` is an `int`.

Comment: Suggestion: turn on all the warnings your compiler emits. Read those warnings and understand them. Eventually write code with no warnings :)

Comment: BTW: the 2nd loop "works" because `917 - 0.5` is `916.5` which gets converted to the `int` value of `916` and so on decreasing by `1` each time (`915.5` converted to `915`, `914.5` converted to `914`, ...).

Answer (score 4):

Two issues:

1. You put a semicolon after the `for` loop's close paren, so that block below it (that does `a++;`) isn't connected to the `for` loop at all, it's just a random sub-block that executes once and exits. Delete that semicolon after the close parenthesis, and it will do what you expect.
2. `n` is an `int`, it can't take values with decimal points. Each `- 0.5` gets truncated back down to `int` when assigned back to `n`, so it ends up being equivalent to `- 1` each time, and the loop only runs 917 times. Change the declaration of `n` to make it a `double`, not an `int`, and it will do what you expect.

Comment: `printf("%.2lf " , a );` wrong printf format

Comment: @0___________: `a` is a `double` (for some reason), so `%.2lf` will work just fine. [`lf` and `f` will work the same for `printf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25860877/364696), so the `l` is superfluous, but harmless. The precision is pointless (it's only ever manipulated in whole number units, so showing *any* decimal places is silly), but it's functional, just weird.

Comment: @0___________: It's not a "works for me" scenario, and you're being quite insulting for someone who is *very* wrong. You're thinking of `%Lf` (capital L), which *does* mean `long double`. `%lf` and `%f` mean *the same thing* for `printf` as of C99. `float` is promoted to `double` when passed to a varargs function like `printf`, there *can't* be a useful format code for `printf` that distinguishes the two (the distinction only matters for `scanf`, which receives a pointer to a specific type and can make the distinction).

Comment: sorry .........